# getting different answer when using Residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula, singular-integrals

I have the following integral: $$\oint_{\left | z \right | = 1}{\frac{z+\bar{z}}{\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}}dz}$$
In the official answer, they calculate that using Cauchy's integral formula and the answer is: $$\frac{\pi}{2}i$$
I'm trying to solve this using the Residue theorem but I get different answer.

First, I wanted to find the singularities points, so:
$$\frac{z+\bar{z}}{\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}} = \frac{z}{z}\cdot \frac{z+\bar{z}}{\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}} = \frac{z^{2}+\left | z \right |^{2}}{\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}} = \frac{z^{2}+1}{z\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}}$$
and now, I can see that my points are: $$z_{1}=0$$
$$z_{2}=\frac{i}{2}$$but I'm getting that:$$Res(f,0)=1$$
$$Res(f,\frac{i}{2})=\frac{5}{4}$$
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The residue at $z=0$ is not $1$.

Comment: @WimC OMG thank you, I look out how I calculated the limit and I mistake by writing "1" instead of "i", now the residue at $z=0$ is $-1$ and the sums of the residues is correct! 

Comment: By the way, not that it makes a big difference here, but it might be easier just to substitute $\bar z = 1/z$ at the outset, rather than doing the manipulation you did. Of course, it all ends up the same.

Answer (score 1):

thank to @WimC, I found My mistake:

$$Res(f,0)=-1$$ and therefore:
$$\oint_{\left | z \right | = 1}{\frac{z+\bar{z}}{\left ( 2z-i \right )^{2}}dz} = 2\pi \cdot i\cdot ((-1)+\frac{5}{4})=\frac{\pi \cdot i}{2}$$ as expected.